# Prove that the automorphism group of the symmetric group on three elements is soluble (solvable)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The definition of soluble (solvable)

A group G is called solvable if it has a subnormal series whose factor groups are all abelian, that is, if there are subgroups $\{1\}=G_r\leq G_{r-1}\leq\cdots\leq G_0=G$ such that  $G_{j+1}$ is normal in$ G_j$, and $G_{j}/G_{j+1} $is an abelian group, for $j=0,1,2\dots,r-1$.

I know that $S_3$ is a solvable group but when it comes to the group of all the automorphisms $S_3\to S_3$, i couldn't really prove that this group is solvable.

Any hints would be great as i have no idea how to do it. How can we shows there is subgroup of the group of all isomorphism from $S_3\to S_3$ which satisfies the above condition? Or is there any easier theorem, lemma which can be used?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative that does not entail finding precisely what the automorphism group is:

Since $S_3$ is generated by the elements of order $2$, any automorphism is uniquely determined by what it does to these elements. Since an automorphism must permute the elements of order $2$ and there are $3$ such elements, this means that there are at most $3! = 6$ possibilities for automorphisms.

That all groups of order at most $6$ are solvable is an easy exercise.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\operatorname {Aut}(S_3) \cong S_3$, try to prove that first.

Comment: Try to prove that..."first"? That'd be the whole solution as the OP *knows* $\;S_3\;$ is solvable.

Comment: Exactly, but Mathematics (hmm dumb name) did not recognize the automorphism group as such. Btw thanks for the hint to my hint!

Answer (score 2):

Nicky's answer gives you the hint, and I'll try to give the hint to the hint.

You may know that  $\;S_3=\langle (12)\,,\,(123)\,\rangle\;$ ,  and since an automorphism keeps order of elements invariant, you have

$$\begin{align*}\phi_1:&(12)\mapsto (12)&,\;\;\;(123)\mapsto (123)\\
\phi_2:&(12)\mapsto (12)&, \;\;\;(123)\mapsto (132)\\
\phi_3:&(12)\mapsto(13)&,\;\;\;(123)\mapsto (123)\\\text{etc.}&\ldots\end{align*}$$